# Problems building wxwidgets in cygwin

Tags: cygwin, wxwidgets

I followed all the instructions provided in the docs/msw/install.txt file for building wxWidgets 3.0.2 using cygwin with all the necessary tools installed.
And even after using the configure script with all the different possible options.
But still it doesn't build properly.The configure script executes correctly but when i use make it shows me this error.
Error:
**cannot convert ‘wxString’ to ‘const void*’ for argument ‘2’ to ‘ssize_t cygwin_conv_path(cygwin_conv_path_t, const void*, void*, size_t)’
             cygwin_conv_path(CCP_POSIX_TO_WIN_W, strDir, windowsPath, MAX_PATH);**

If any one can help me on this i will highly appreciate it.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, are you absolutely sure that you really want to use the Cygwin port of wxWidgets? This is almost never a good idea and it's strongly recommended to use Cygwin as the build environment for building the native MSW port using MinGW (cross-)compiler as explained [in this post](http://wxwidgets.blogspot.com/2011/06/choosing-gcc-for-building-wxwidgets.html).

If you really do need Cygwin, it looks like you need to insert `.c_str()` call here, i.e. write `cygwin_conv_path(CCP_POSIX_TO_WIN_W, strDir.c_str(), windowsPath, MAX_PATH)`, as you're probably using `--enable-stl` and the implicit conversion is not available.